# How do I send form data from the client side to the server

Tags: node.js, forms

So. I have a form that is supposed to send username and password to server when it's submitted. I have searched the web, and all of them were for sending data from client to other servers(like an api). What I want is to send data to the server that is hosting the client from the client. I have tried using websockets, but they get in the way of a different part of the code. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
loginForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    var f = new FormData()
    f.set('usrnm', document.getElementById('loginUsername'))
    f.set('psw', document.getElementById('loginPassword'))
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any code written for it already? There are tons of examples online, what are some of the articles you've read that didn't answer your question. regardless you will need to make a POST request to your back end. Depending on your server side language you'll need to handle that request differently but they are *normally* your own API(endpoint).

Comment: So I just need to send the data the same way I would send it if I were interacting with my api?

Comment: When you retrieve data from the back end it is done the same way you would do it from a 3rd party source, a GET request. Based on permissions and if you will need an API token, not always it depends on who set up the back end, what APIs you are using etc. If it is yours then you wouldn't have to worry about it.